# 404 not found error when adding microsoft.jquery.Unobtrusive.ajax library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

When I add this library to a project, I can't access any new `ActionResult` I had added to project.

Comment: Hi Parham and welcome to stack overflow :), could you provide us with a bit more detail? Where are you getting the 404 error, when you run the project, where did you add the library from? NuGet? Could you provide us with some code related to this?

Comment: @david-rogers Hi David and thanks . i had added this library from NuGet and after that when I create a new Action Result and add a view to it and call this action i get this error.but the older action result are accessible and they load their views

Comment: Could you post the code from both your view and controller of the old code/new code, and a screenshot of your NuGet Configuration?